# Working with structure arrays in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have the following contract code example:

```
contract C {

    struct A {
        uint256 a;
        uint256 b;
    }

    struct B {
        A ax;
        uint256 c;
    }

    struct C {
        string name;
        B[] bs;
    }

    function init() {
        C memory c;
        B memory b;
        A memory a;

        a.a = 10;
        a.b = 20;

        b.ax = a;
        b.c = 30;

        c.name = "Test test test";
        c.bs[0] = b;
    }
}
```

Why can't I use push for the last statement

```
 c.bs[0] = b;
```

:

```
c.bs.push(b);
```

It throws the following error:

```
Untitled:30:9: Error: Member "push" is not available in struct B memory[] memory outside of storage.
        c.bs.push(b);
        ^-------^
```

but **bs** is an array of structures.

Comment: Not completely related to the original question but to comment on Roland's comment: > Memory arrays have always a fixed length. Memory arrays can have variable length by initializing them with the `new` keyword. http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#arrays

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Push is available only on `storage` arrays, that is member/ state variables and not in `memory` arrays, that is local variables:

> push: Dynamic storage arrays and bytes (not string) have a member
>   function called push that can be used to append an element at the end
>   of the array. The function returns the new length.

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html

Comment: So it's not possible to initialize a struct that contains an array and is stored in memory and then later append it as an element to an array in storage?

Comment: from what I understand this is perfectly possible using `push`, but not the other way around. Memory arrays have always a fixed length.

Answer (score 10):

Explaining further what [atc](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/working-with-structure-arrays-in-solidity#comment25674_7210) mentioned in their comment,

## Fixed vs variable length

- **Memory arrays** have fixed length, which means their length cannot be modified after it is initialized. Since `push()` appends a new element at the end of the array, it is not available for memory arrays.
- **Storage arrays**, on the other hand, can have variable length. Yet, they're more expensive. Do you have to use storage arrays for your use case? Maybe not; keep reading.

## Static vs dynamic length

- **Static-length arrays** are initialized with a length defined at compile time, which is specified inside the array's square brackets. If you want to initialize them with a length that's not defined at compile time, you'll get an error:

```
function bar(uint baz) public {
    uint[7] memory foo1; // this is fine
    uint[7] storage foo2; // this is fine
    uint[baz] memory foo3; // this throws a compile-time error
    uint[baz] storage foo4; // this throws a compile-time error
}
```

As you can see, this applies for both memory and storage arrays.

- **Dynamic-length** arrays are initialized with a length defined at runtime, which is specified by means of the `new` keyword and written inside parentheses after the array's square brackets:

```
function bar(uint baz) public {
    uint[] memory foo1 = new uint[](7); // this is fine
    uint[] storage foo2 = new uint[](7); // this is fine
    uint[] memory foo3 = new uint[](baz); // this is fine
    uint[] storage foo4 = new uint[](baz); // this is fine
}
```