# Member X is not available in struct Y memory outside of storage

Tags: solidity

I've been coding in solidity and got this error "Member "betsOnBitcoinGoesUp" is not available in struct BetOnBitcoinNew.BettingObject memory outside of storage." What does this mean?

The function that produced error looks like this.

```
function getUserBetsfromBettingObject(uint index, address callerAddress) constant returns (uint) {
BettingObject memory currentBettingObject = arrayOfBettingObjects[index];
if (currentBettingObject.currentState == GameState.bitcoinUpWon) {
  return currentBettingObject.betsOnBitcoinGoesUp[callerAddress];
} else if (currentBettingObject.currentState == GameState.bitcoinDownWon) {
  return currentBettingObject.betsOnBitcoinGoesDown[callerAddress];
} else {
  return 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As MSwezey states. The issue is because `currentBettingObject` is declared as `BettingObject memory`, not `BettingObject storage`.

Memory in the EVM is an array. Storage is a key value map (aka `mapping`). 
A map can not be represented as an array as they are fundamentally different data structures. Therefore Solidity `mapping`'s only exist in storage they cannot exist in memory.

When doing `BettingObject memory currentBettingObject = arrayOfBettingObjects[index];` you copy a `BettingObject` from storage into memory but since the mapping in the `BettingObject` can't be represented in the memory structure available (an array), it isn't copied and you get the error when trying to access it. If you replace that line with `BettingObject storage currentBettingObject = arrayOfBettingObjects[index];` it will work since you're accessing the `BettingObject` in storage directly without copying it.

Comment: Much better explanation that I was too lazy to type. Well said!

Answer (score 1):

I imported into my VS Code and got the same error.

The problem lies with the `memory` keyword used. 
Switching it to `storage` fixes this problem and the compiler error goes away.

Why?

See Roland's answer: [Working with structure arrays in solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/working-with-structure-arrays-in-solidity)