# Error ; Member "push" is not available in address[] memory outside of storage

Tags: solidity, arrays

I am writing a function to generate trail of all address who owned an asset ( assets is a mapping of asset no to owner no to address of owner).
However while making array of address 'listofOwners' I get compilation error, *Member "push" is not available in address[] memory outside of storage.*

```
function viewTrail(uint256 _assetNo) public view returns(address[] memory){
   address[] memory listofOwners = new address[](assets[_assetNo].ownerNo);
  for(ownerNo = 1; ownerNo<= assets[_assetNo].ownerNo; ownerNo ++)
  {
  listofOwners.push(owneraddr[_assetNo][ownerNo]);
  }

return listofOwners;}
```

Can you please suggest a solution or some other code to generate trail of owners of an asset?

Comment: Check that [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/working-with-structure-arrays-in-solidity).

Answer (score 6):

You can assign the elements to the array position by referencing the element key like `myArray[0] = ‘new value’;`

The following example uses a `view` function, because the array is in `memory`:

```
function getMultipleAddresses( string[] calldata ids) public view returns (address[] memory) {

    address[] memory _addresses = new address[](ids.length);
    
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
      string memory id = ids[i];
      require(_idToAddress[id] != address(0), 'Missing address');
      address payable _address = payable(_addresses[i]);

      _addresses[i] = _address;
    }
    return  _addresses;
}
```