# "The called function should be payable" even though no payment is processed

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.8.x

Hello i'm writing an 1155 contract and have a function as follows:

```
  function creditPowls(address _to) public onlyOwner {
    uint256[] memory ids; 
    uint256[] memory vals; 
    for (uint i=0; i<=12; i++) {
      minted++;
      ids[i] = minted;
      vals[i] = 1;
    }
    _mintBatch(_to, ids, vals, "");
  }
```

but i'm getting the following error even though i'm not really dealing with payment.

> revert: The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
> Debug the transaction to get more information.

thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Is the contract deployed on a testnet somewhere? Can you share its address?

Comment: it isn't i'm stil testing it on the remix ide built in accounts.

Comment: The error is 100% misleading. Nothing to do with being payable. It is just a default revert statement. You might want to make sure that you use the owners account when you mint, and also that the _to address is not 0x0

Answer (score 2):

solution for whom have a similar problem:

> Kenzo Agada — Today at 3:29 PM That error is misleading, it might show
> it sometimes even when the error is not related to payable The problem
> is probably in how you use the arrays - they seem to be a dynamic
> type, no length, but you assign to them at a specific location - that
> location is not created yet Will your array always have size 12? 13
> actually

> Kenzo Agada — Today at 3:31 PM So change your declaration like this

```
uint256[13] memory ids;  
uint256[13] memory vals;
```

> This should create the arrays with size 13, and so when you'll do
> ids[0] for example, it will be able to set it

> OWLΞTH — Today at 4:08 PM @Kenzo Agada i was getting and invalid
> explicit conversion from a fixed to dynamic type, writing it with a
> fixed size (mintBatch wants it dynamic). found a solution on the
> internet to do

```
uint256[] memory ids = new uint256[](12).
```

> all errors
> are gone now but i'm not sure about this syntax .. it's giving length
> to a dynamic array instead of a pre-fixed size?

> Kenzo Agada — Today at 4:32 PM Yay I found the mythical post I was
> referring to
> [Working with structure arrays in solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/working-with-structure-arrays-in-solidity/82580#82580)

[image: static vs dynamic]